# Redirect from http to https on localhost with create-react-app to test with Lighthouse

Tags: reactjs, redirect, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I have configured create-react-app to use https in my local development environment. I would now like to convert my React application to a progressive web app and I plan to use Lighthouse to check my status. I am running Lighthouse as a Chrome plugin, but I am having trouble with the part when it is checking if my HTTP requests are redirected to HTTPS. They are not.

I have been crawling through my node_modules and I have taken a look at webpack-dev-server that is bundled with create-react-app. I have tried to make some changes, but the best I have managed so far is that I have gotten "Too many redirects".

TL;DR: How can I configure create-react-app to redirect all requests from http to https on my local dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from my `create-react-app` if you are having trouble with just the redirect part. I'm doing it manually since [Heroku doesn't automatically handle it](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls). But this actually needs to be handled on the server because it makes the app visibly load twice if it has to redirect to http. But for now, I'm redirecting in the constructor of my App component.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  const url = window.location.origin
  if (!url.includes('localhost') && !url.includes('https')) {
    window.location = `https:${url.split(':'))[1]}`
  }
}
```

For your purposes, you'd just need to take out the localhost part and make the new url a little differently (because of the port).

I'm using [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tail) here, but [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#tail) also has a tail function you can use.

```
import { tail } from 'ramda

...

constructor(props, context) {
  const url = window.location.origin
  if (!url.includes('https')) {
    window.location = `https:${tail(url.split(':')).join(':')}`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fmacs, for redirection of HTTP traffic to HTTPS, instead of using local dev-server, deploy your app on any environment like Heroku or Firebase. Firebase is very simple. I see that you also have other issues running the create-react-app that you created. I have explained how to do this in simple steps in a blog post with sample code in GitHub. Please refer to: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2019/10/react-pwa-tutorial.html